# Find after initials in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, find, conditional-statements

How should a specific find function look in cakephp? I have this criteria: I want to search by a given code that is formed of 2 letters and 5 numbers. The two letters are the initials of the first two words in a field and the numbers are meant to match a field.

For example I have the `code=PG35478` and after this I want to find the user that in his name field is Phillip George and has the postal code 35478.

So:

```
$user = $this->User->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => [...?]
        ));
```

Comment: Updating your tables and adding an extra field that holds these codes is out of question? And what about "duplicates", for example Peter Gabriel in 35478?

Comment: ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version! And when asking questions regarding queries, it's also helpful to know what DBMS and table type you are using.

Comment: I agree that an extra field that holds these codes would be the easiest.  If it's absolutely necessary to not have this field, you may be able to search by regular expressions.  Like if you are using mysql, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: If it's indeed about MySQL, and in case a little more loose match would be OK, then I'd suggest using `LIKE`, as opposed to a regex match it can make use of indices. @user2076809

Comment: I would have said LIKE as well, but LIKE may or may not be precise enough, depending on what data can be expected and such.

Comment: Sure, just wanted to mention it for the sake of completeness. @user2076809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*{Edited for improved SQL Injection protection}*

Assuming you broke the code into its components for readability:  $first_char, $second_char, $postal

Also assuming your database fields are called namefield and postalfield.

Then use this

```
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
'namefield LIKE' => "'" . $first_char . "% " . $second_char . "%'",
'postalfield' => $postal
)));
```

*There is a space after the first percent sign*

Comment: That style of syntax is prone to **SQL injections**! `LIKE` expressions should use the `key => value` style too: `'field LIKE' => '%term%'`